# Redirect user to a dynamic url after success authentication

Tags: facebook, symfony, router, hwioauthbundle

In my `Symfony2` project i am using `HWIOauthBundle` to `login` users with `facebook` account. and what i wanna do is redirect the user to a `route` that has `parameters` after a success `login`. Is there any way to set `default_target_path` in `firewall` as dynamic?

this is the `route` that i want to redirect the user to:

```
my_route:
    pattern:  /upload/{caseNumber}/{token}
    defaults: { _controller: UploadBundle:Upload:upload}
```

and the firewall configuration:

```
 firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false        

        main:
            anonymous: true
            pattern: ^/
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook: "/login/check-facebook"
                login_path:   /login
                failure_path: /login
                default_target_path: /upload/00044710/500f5BBQP
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: ib_user.oauth_user_provider                
            remember_me:
                key:     "%secret%"
```

the problem as you can see in `default_target_path: /upload/00044710/500f5BBQP` is that the `case number` and `token` can change. So how can i set it dynamically .

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to an action that will find the correct url and further redirect the user.

Comment: can you specify what changes i should apply in `firewall` configuration

Comment: default_target_path: /my_custom_action

and create an action that will find the correct path for current case and redirect the user